# recycler view data not showing after run time permission check

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't seem to figure out how do I display data after run time allow permission button is pressed.The data is in a recycler view

The permission dialog works correctly because this gives me correct result on log cat but I cannot seem to get data on mobile device

Here is the code:

```html
    private val requestMultiplePermissions =registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->

            if (permissions[READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] == true && permissions[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] == true) {
                getMusicList()
            } else {
                checkPermissions()
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission not granted")
            }
        }
        
   private fun checkPermissions(){
        if (context?.let {
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it,
                    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
                arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        }
        else {
            requestMultiplePermissions
        }

    }
    
     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
     
     checkPermissions()
     }
```

Comment: Why your code is hard to read? and why are you asking for permissions in your adapter that's weird, And what does getMusicList() function do?

Comment: get Music List is a function that query me in media store and get me the list of songs. I am not asking permissions in my adapter this is my fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun checkPermissions() {
    if (context?.let {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                it,
                READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        } != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
            arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
    } else {
        //requestMultiplePermissions

        getMusicList()
    }

}
```

Do not need to request permission again when it is granted

Comment: why my recycler view data is not displayed?

Comment: there are many possible reasons. One of them is what I have suggested above, you did not get music list when permission is granted

Comment: Sorry that did not solve anything